# Pythonでステガノグラフィーを試したいと思ったがエラーがでました。

Tags: python

ステガノグラフィーなるものをドラマで知ったので使ってみたいと思いPythonをインストールして以下のコードをコピペして実行しました。choose fileでjpgの画像を選択しましたが読み込まれません。

encript.py

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

global path_image

image_display_size = 300, 300

def on_click():
    # Step 1.5
    global path_image
    # use the tkinter filedialog library to open the file using a dialog box.
    # obtain the image of the path
    path_image = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    # load the image using the path
    load_image = Image.open(path_image)
    # set the image into the GUI using the thumbnail function from tkinter
    load_image.thumbnail(image_display_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # load the image as a numpy array for efficient computation and change the type to unsigned integer
    np_load_image = np.asarray(load_image)
    np_load_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np_load_image))
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(np_load_image)
    img = Label(app, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=20, y=50)

def encrypt_data_into_image():
    # Step 2
    global path_image
    data = txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    # load the image
    img = cv2.imread(path_image)
    # break the image into its character level. Represent the characyers in ASCII.
    data = [format(ord(i), '08b') for i in data]
    _, width, _ = img.shape
    # algorithm to encode the image
    PixReq = len(data) * 3

    RowReq = PixReq/width
    RowReq = math.ceil(RowReq)

    count = 0
    charCount = 0
    # Step 3
    for i in range(RowReq + 1):
        # Step 4
        while(count < width and charCount < len(data)):
            char = data[charCount]
            charCount += 1
            # Step 5
            for index_k, k in enumerate(char):
                if((k == '1' and img[i][count][index_k % 3] % 2 == 0) or (k == '0' and img[i][count][index_k % 3] % 2 == 1)):
                    img[i][count][index_k % 3] -= 1
                if(index_k % 3 == 2):
                    count += 1
                if(index_k == 7):
                    if(charCount*3 < PixReq and img[i][count][2] % 2 == 1):
                        img[i][count][2] -= 1
                    if(charCount*3 >= PixReq and img[i][count][2] % 2 == 0):
                        img[i][count][2] -= 1
                    count += 1
        count = 0
    # Step 6
    # Write the encrypted image into a new file
    cv2.imwrite("encrypted_image.png", img)
    # Display the success label.
    success_label = Label(app, text="Encryption Successful!",
                bg='lavender', font=("Times New Roman", 20))
    success_label.place(x=160, y=300)

# Step 1
# Defined the TKinter object app with background lavender, title Encrypt, and app size 600*600 pixels.
app = Tk()
app.configure(background='lavender')
app.title("Encrypt")
app.geometry('600x600')
# create a button for calling the function on_click
on_click_button = Button(app, text="Choose Image", bg='white', fg='black', command=on_click)
on_click_button.place(x=250, y=10)
# add a text box using tkinter's Text function and place it at (340,55). The text box is of height 165pixels.
txt = Text(app, wrap=WORD, width=30)
txt.place(x=340, y=55, height=165)

encrypt_button = Button(app, text="Encode", bg='white', fg='black', command=encrypt_data_into_image)
encrypt_button.place(x=435, y=230)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: エラーが出たならそれらのメッセージも質問に含めてください。また、「コピペして」との事なので、出典のURL等を明記してください。 / 質問にあたっては [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考にしてみてください。

Comment: 元はこちらの記事だと思われます。[Steganography - An Experiment in Python](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/steganography-in-python/)

Comment: Windows10 64bit Python 3.9.1で他パッケージも最新でちょっと動かした程度では問題無く動作するようです。ありそうなのが、画像ファイルのパスに空白や全角文字が含まれていたとかパス名のエンコードが違うとか、ネットやクラウド上のファイルだったとか。サポートされていない形式とかでしょうか。

Comment: エラーはどの行でどんなエラーが出たのでしょうか？(エラー詳細を追記してください。)